# Correctly handing NAN in PHP versions

Tags: php, nan

Can anyone explain why `NAN` and a variable equal to `NAN` behave differently depending on the version of PHP?

Consider the following code:

```
$nan = NAN;
print "PHP Version: " . phpversion(). "\n" .
  '0 <  NAN ? ' . ( 0 < NAN   ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE' ) . "\n" .
  '0 >  NAN ? ' . ( 0 > NAN   ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE' ) . "\n" . 
  '0 == NAN ? ' . ( 0 == NAN  ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE' ) . "\n" . 
  '0 <  $nan ? ' . ( 0 < $nan  ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE' ) . "\n" .
  '0 >  $nan ? ' . ( 0 > $nan  ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE' ) . "\n" .
  '0 == $nan ? ' . ( 0 == $nan ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE' ) . "\n" .
  'is_nan(NAN) ' . ( is_nan(NAN)  ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE' ) . "\n" .
  'is_nan($nan) ' . ( is_nan($nan) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE' ) . "\n" .
  'gettype(NAN) is '  . gettype(NAN)  . "\n" .
  'gettype($nan) is ' . gettype($nan) . "\n";
```

Now, if I run this code against many versions of PHP (using MAMP) the following are results:

```
PHP Version: 5.3.5
0 <  NAN ? TRUE
0 >  NAN ? TRUE
0 == NAN ? FALSE
0 <  $nan ? TRUE
0 >  $nan ? TRUE
0 == $nan ? FALSE
is_nan(NAN) TRUE
is_nan($nan) TRUE
gettype(NAN) is double
gettype($nan) is double

PHP Version: 5.6.30 (and 5.5.30, 5.4.45)
0 <  NAN ? FALSE
0 >  NAN ? FALSE
0 == NAN ? FALSE
0 <  $nan ? FALSE
0 >  $nan ? FALSE
0 == $nan ? FALSE
is_nan(NAN) TRUE
is_nan($nan) TRUE
gettype(NAN) is double
gettype($nan) is double

PHP Version: 7.1.1 (and 7.0.15)
0 <  NAN ? TRUE
0 >  NAN ? TRUE
0 == NAN ? FALSE
0 <  $nan ? FALSE
0 >  $nan ? FALSE
0 == $nan ? FALSE
is_nan(NAN) TRUE
is_nan($nan) TRUE
gettype(NAN) is double
gettype($nan) is double
```

Can a function in PHP rely on a comparison to NAN or should NAN only be used with `is_nan()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This bug has now been fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/c562d44321ea69612fbe3f7460055e9ed4340baa). The explanation bellow shows what was causing it.

About your first question, it seems that since PHP7 you get different results depending on whether the expression is evaluated during compilation or during runtime.

First off, it is important to note that according to IEEE754 all comparisions where one of the elements is a `NAN`, should return `false`. You can find some details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573715/291626). Taking that into account, the behavior of 5.6 seems to be the correct one.

---

So, for the case of runtime evaluation(`0 < $nan`), that comparison is done in the VM by [this code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/c908caf6dfd2f64ee2a72137f1bdb32a73e0e0e0/Zend/zend_vm_def.h#L536):

```
result = ((double)Z_LVAL_P(op1) < Z_DVAL_P(op2));
```

That operation will assign 0 to `result` which is eventually returned. This will give us the expected output of `FALSE`.

---

In the case of compile time evaluation(`0 < NAN`), the comparison ir done during compilation by [this code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/c908caf6dfd2f64ee2a72137f1bdb32a73e0e0e0/Zend/zend_operators.c#L1920-L1923):

```
case TYPE_PAIR(IS_LONG, IS_DOUBLE):
    Z_DVAL_P(result) = (double)Z_LVAL_P(op1) - Z_DVAL_P(op2);
    ZVAL_LONG(result, ZEND_NORMALIZE_BOOL(Z_DVAL_P(result)));
    return SUCCESS;
```

Here there are some other things happening, the result of the subtraction `0 - NAN = NAN` that value then goes through the `ZEND_NORMALIZE_BOOL` macro that reads as follows:

```
#define ZEND_NORMALIZE_BOOL(n)          \
    ((n) ? (((n)>0) ? 1 : -1) : 0)
```

As you can see, if `(n) > 0` is `false` (which is the case for `NAN`), the macro will return `-1`.
That value is then passed to the `is_smaller_function` where [you'll find](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/c908caf6dfd2f64ee2a72137f1bdb32a73e0e0e0/Zend/zend_operators.c#L2180):

```
ZVAL_BOOL(result, (Z_LVAL_P(result) < 0));
```

Given that at this point `result` holds `-1`, this will be evaluated to `TRUE`.

---

About your second question, I would suggest you should never rely on comparisons with `NAN` and stick to using `is_nan()`. Note that even `NAN == NAN` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the detective work.  It would seem that it is an oddity that in 7+ you get the TRUE result in compile-based evaluation.  The take home for me is to avoid the potential for any NAN comparisons...

Comment: It was actually fun to figure out. :) FYI, a bug was reported: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74974

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#language.types.float.nan) says about `NaN`:

> **NaN**
>
> Some numeric operations can result in a value represented by the constant `NAN`. This result represents an undefined or unrepresentable value in floating-point calculations. Any loose or strict comparisons of this value against any other value, including itself, but except `TRUE`, will have a result of `FALSE`.
>
> Because `NAN` represents any number of different values, `NAN` should not be compared to other values, including itself, and instead should be checked for using [`is_nan()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-nan.php).

In plain English, `NaN` is not a value. It is a notation that denotes a result that cannot be computed or stored using the internal representation of real numbers using the floating point standard.

`NaN` is not equal to anything else. `NaN` is not equal even with another `NaN` because many different computations can produce `NaN`.

The only reliable way to check if a result is `NaN` is to use the [`is_nan()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-nan.php) function.

Only the last four tests from your code are valid:

```
is_nan(NAN) TRUE
is_nan($nan) TRUE
gettype(NAN) is double
gettype($nan) is double
```